# Can't able to send SMS using Twilio Trail Account using C#

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api

I'm just trying to use Twilio to send transaction SMS. I have tried exactly the same code which is provided in the Twilio Documentation

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/console
            const string accountSid = "AC5270abb139629daeb8f3c205ec632155";
            const string authToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"),
                body: "Body",
                to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("MyNumber")
            );

            Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

in this authToken copy from Twilio console and the TO number is my number which is used to register on Twilio. I also have verified the number in Verified Caller IDs segment in Twilio Console. 
From Number initially, I was using the number which is generated by in Twilio Console the Number Belongs to the US but it won't work. After Reading this 
[Article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183808-Why-aren-t-my-test-credentials-working-) I used the Exact code provided by Twilio just make the Changes as authToken and TO Number. But still, it won't work.

I have No idea why it Does not Work. is that you Can't Send the message from one country to another country?

Comment: If message is queued you get `message.sid` and it will be delivered, else are you getting any exception then?

Comment: Twilio Error Code: 30008 from the Twilio Console @Chenna

Comment: To confirm, are you using your production credentials to send the message (don't use test credentials)? Have you checked the documentation for [Error 30008](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30008) and checked all the potential solutions there? If you are possibly having trouble sending to different countries then check your [SMS geo permissions](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

As I want to Verify Mobile number by sending code from SMS. so achieve this I'm using
Twilio Verify API [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api) where the Code is generated by Twilio and verified by himself.

this Solve my problem.

TO Send SMS :-

```
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
  new KeyValuePair<string,string>("via", "sms"),
  new KeyValuePair<string,string>("phone_number", "Moblienumber"),
  new KeyValuePair<string,string>("country_code", "CountryCode"),
});

            // https://api.authy.com/protected/$AUTHY_API_FORMAT/phones/verification/start?via=$VIA&country_code=$USER_COUNTRY&phone_number=$USER_PHONE
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
              "https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/start?api_key=" + "Your Key",
              requestContent);

            // Get the response content.
            HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

            // Get the stream of the content.
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                // Write the output.
                Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
            }
            return Ok();
```

To Verify :-

```
// Create client
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // Add authentication header
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Authy-API-Key", "Your Key");

        // https://api.authy.com/protected/$AUTHY_API_FORMAT/phones/verification/check?phone_number=$USER_PHONE&country_code=$USER_COUNTRY&verification_code=$VERIFY_CODE
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
          "https://api.authy.com/protected/json/phones/verification/check?phone_number=phone_number&country_code=country_code&verification_code=CodeReceivedbySMS ");

        // Get the response content.
        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        // Get the stream of the content.
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {
            // Write the output.
            Console.WriteLine(await reader.ReadToEndAsync());
        }
        return Ok();
```